# How to fix the error Type 'string | ChatCompletionContentPart[] | null' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: typescript, next.js, openai-api

I'm developing my very first Saas App like a ChatGPT with NextJs using OpenAI Api. However I developed most part of the app following a youtube tutorial and suddenly sticked on two errors due to a version update of OpenAI. I've tried everything possible and I couldn't solve the problem.

I'm sharing below the page.tsx file's code where the error is.

```
"use client";

import axios from "axios";
import * as z from "zod";
import { Bot } from "lucide-react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import { Heading } from "@/components/heading";
import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem } from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Empty } from "@/components/empty";
import { Loader } from "@/components/loader";

import { formSchema } from "./constants";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useState } from "react";
import { ChatCompletionMessageParam } from "openai/resources/chat/completions";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { UserAvatar } from "@/components/user-avatar";
import { BotAvatar } from "@/components/bot-avatar";

const ConversationPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<ChatCompletionMessageParam[]>([]);

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      prompt: "",
    },
  });

  const isLoading = form.formState.isSubmitting;

  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    try {
      const userMessage: ChatCompletionMessageParam = {
        role: "user",
        content: values.prompt,
      };
      const newMessages = [...messages, userMessage];

      const response = await axios.post("/api/sociagpt", {
        messages: newMessages,
      });

      setMessages((current) => [...current, userMessage, response.data]);
      form.reset();
    } catch (error: any) {
      //Remember for later
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      router.refresh();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Heading
        title="SociaGPT"
        description="An advance chatbot for social media marketing strategies."
        icon={Bot}
        iconColor="text-violet-500"
        bgColor="bg-violet-500/10"
      />
      <div className="px-4 lg:px-8">
        <div>
          <Form {...form}>
            <form
              onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
              className="rounded-lg
                border
                w-full
                p-4
                px-3
                md:px-6
                focus-within:shadow-sm
                grid
                grid-cols-12
                gap-2 "
            >
              <FormField
                name="prompt"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-10">
                    <FormControl className="m-0 p-0">
                      <Input
                        className="border-0 outline-none focus-visible:ring-0 focus-visible:ring-transparent"
                        disabled={isLoading}
                        placeholder="What is the best marketing strategy to follow in 2024?"
                        {...field}
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
              <Button
                className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-2 w-full"
                disabled={isLoading}
              >
                Ask Socia
              </Button>
            </form>
          </Form>
        </div>
        <div className="space-y-4 mt-4">
          {isLoading && (
            <div className="p-8 rounded-lg w-full flex items-center justify-center bg-muted">
              <Loader />
            </div>
          )}
          {messages.length === 0 && !isLoading && (
            <Empty label="No conversation started yet." />
          )}
          <div className="flex flex-col-reverse gap-y-4">
            {messages.map((message) => (
              <div
                key={message.content}
                className={cn(
                  "p-8 w-fiull flex items-start gap-x-8 rounded-lg",
                  message.role === "user"
                    ? "bg-white border border-black/10"
                    : "bg-muted"
                )}
              >
                {message.role === "user" ? <UserAvatar /> : <BotAvatar />}
                <p className="text-sm">{message.content}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ConversationPage;
```

The two errors are inside the below code snippet:

1. Type 'string | ChatCompletionContentPart[] | null' is not assignable to type 'Key | null | undefined'.
2. Type 'string | ChatCompletionContentPart[] | null' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

```
<div
                **key={message.content}**
                className={cn(
                  "p-8 w-fiull flex items-start gap-x-8 rounded-lg",
                  message.role === "user"
                    ? "bg-white border border-black/10"
                    : "bg-muted"
                )}
              >
                {message.role === "user" ? <UserAvatar /> : <BotAvatar />}
                <p className="text-sm">**{message.content**}</p>
              </div>
```

Below mentioned code is for the route file called route.ts:

```
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { OpenAI } from "openai";

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const { userId } = auth();
    const body = await req.json();
    const { messages } = body;

    if (!userId) {
      return new NextResponse("Unaothorized", { status: 401 });
    }

    if (!openai.apiKey) {
      return new NextResponse("OpenAI API Key not configured", { status: 500 });
    }

    if (!messages) {
      return new NextResponse("Messages are required", { status: 400 });
    }

    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages,
    });
    return NextResponse.json(response.choices[0].message);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("[CONVERSATION_ERROR]", error);
    return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

I tried every solution provided on the platforms like stackoverflow and github. Nothing fixed my issues.

Any solution that solves my errors appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The error is the fact that the key prop being used in the code is to identify and track items in a list, it needs to have a unique value for each item in the list. You are providing it with an array using ChatCompletionContentPart[] when the key value needs to be a string or simply null or undefined. To fix provide valid value for key prop.

Answer (score 0):

Use String(message.content) ensures that the key prop is a string. Make sure that message.content is not undefined or null at this point, as TypeScript is complaining about those possibilities as well.

key={String(message.content)}